# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: setValue:forUndefinedKey, _requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback

Tags: xcode, ionic3

I'm trying to use the xcode emulator, but keep getting this error on startup:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<WKWebViewConfiguration 0x7f9dce800d40> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback.'
```

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling cordova-plugin-ionic-webview and have exhausted all the solutions I can find here on SO, but they have made no difference.

This is an ionic cordova project, so I can't change any code in xcode, as it will be overwritten the next time I build the project. Any other solutions will be gratefully received.

I'm not sure whether it's related, but when I do an android ionic emulate on the command line, it works, but an ios emulate doesn't and I get this error:

```
/Users/path-to-project/platforms/ios/build/emulator/project.app/Info.plist file not found.
```

The problem is that no build folder under the ios one has been created, which is probably why it can't find anything there. I think I've tracked the problem to the following messages farther up the output:

```
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/path-to-project/platforms/ios/build/emulator
SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/path-to-project/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

However, I don't know where these configs are set. Does anyone know where ionic gets these configs from?

One question comes to mind though: If CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR is set to this location, why isn't the build dir created here?

Comment: FWIW `requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback` is a deprecated property on `WKWebView` since iOS 10. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration/1614794-requiresuseractionformediaplayba.   You need to track down what is attempting to set that property and change it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, there is only one occurrence, which is buried in another plugin, but I can't really change it, as I don't know what it is doing and it'll be lost the next time I update it.

Comment: I've posted an ionic answer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52720464/solution-nsunknownkeyexception-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant):

Answer (score 7):

This one is a doozy and a pretty obscure one that took ages to figure out.

This solution is for ionic. There are loads of 'solutions' out there for Xcode, but they can't be used for ionic projects, as any code changes in the ios folder will be overwritten on the next compile.

The clue is in the message: _requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback. However, another part of the message mentions WKWebView, which is a red herring, as it isn't actually anything to do with the problem.

The actual problem resides in the cordova-plugin-background-mode plugin, in the /cordova-plugin-background-mode/src/ios/APPBackgroundMode.m file to be exact. At the end of the swizzleWKWebViewEngine method, which is at the bottom of the class, change:

```
forKey:@"_requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback"];
```

to:

```
forKey:@"requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback"];
```

i.e. delete the underscore. Yes, it really is that simple and it wasted days of my life finding it.

It's a bug that is mentioned on Github at: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues/381. As at 9th October 2018, the plugin hadn't been updated for 2 years and the bug had still not been corrected in npm, so you have to make the change yourself until it has been.

Comment: @AlphaBeta: sir i have already check but in our file i have set requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback tell me sir what i do know?